# How to use std::function when implementing a HashMap in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, std

I am working on HashMap class with typedef std::function in HashMap class declaration.

```
typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
```

For private member of the class, I have HashFunction hash that can be used with my own hash function or use other function supplied to constructor.

```
HashFunction hash;
unsigned int myHashFunction(const std::string&) const;
```

A default constructor must set the hash to default value which in my case is myHashFunction. And a constructor which a HashFunction as parameter must use that particular function, not myHashFunction.

```
HashMap::HashMap()
  : map(new Node*[INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT]), mapSize(0), mapCapacity(INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT),
  hash(std::bind(&HashMap::myHashFunction, this)) // This is definitely not correct
{
  initializeMap();
}

HashMap::HashMap(HashFunction hashFunction)
  : map(new Node*[INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT]), mapSize(0),     mapCapacity(INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT),
  hash(hashFunction) //Is this correct?
{
  initializeMap();
}
```

How can I bind myHashFunction or a supplied hash function to hash, so that I can use hash(key) in the class member functions to support both hash functions? Please direct me to the right path if I am completely getting it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `std::bind` line, if you're trying to bind a member function then you need to include a placeholder, like so:

```
std::bind(&HashMap::myHashFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

You might find it better to make `myHashFunction` a static member function though, unless it actually uses other members or data in your `HashMap` (my guess is it probably shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `std::hash`? It's defined in the `<functional>` header.

Comment: Well, you could equally ask "why not use `std::unordered_map`?". There's nothing wrong with writing your own version of standard library facilities for educational purposes or just for fun, though of course you should think long and hard whether you really need them in production code.

Comment: Also it is an assignment so I need to write my own hash function.